# why is molybdenum a much stronger magnet than chromium

Tags: magnetism

Molybdenum is well known for its strong magnetic properties. Why is Chromium with an identical set of unpaired electrons not nearly as strong?

Comment: Molybdenum (as well as chromium) is not magnetic at all. You must be confusing it with magnesium, which it not magnetic either.

Comment: For calculating chrome phase diagrams you certainly need to consider the magnetic contributions to the free energy, so I'll disagree with you.

Comment: Thanks to both I was in fact thinking about Neodymium and got confused! Obviously both Mo and Cr, in the solid, must be +6 cations so that no unpaired electrons are left to cause ferro-magnetism!